# Updateing a Kivy ListProperty item works in one function but throws TypeError in another

Tags: python, kivy

I have been working on a Python app with Kivy for several weeks(my first real dive into Python) and have hit a snag with working with a ListProperty() item linked to kv Label text.

The Lists are being created and are populating the Label text using root.var[indx] in the .kv file. My issue comes in updating a specific index point in the ListProperty. I have one function that it works every time. Then another that always errors with:

> TypeError: 'kivy.properties.ListProperty' object does not support item assignment

Part of my code:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty, ListProperty, NumericProperty
import... #continued

class setScreen(screen):
    #other variables here
    trig0 = ['tr0', 'Pre-Mass', 'yuo', '4', 1, colNorm, 'trig0p']
    ...
    trigIndex = {}
    trigList = [trig0, ...]
    trigDict = {'trig0p':trig0p, ...}
    trig0p = ListProperty(trig0[:])
    ...

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        #do init here

    def custController(self):
        #this screen's main functions

#The following function works and the Kivy Label text is updated without issue
    def changeProcess(self, x): #x is list from custController button eg.['trig0p', 'Text', 'New Text', 'more new text', #, 'something']
        itemToChange = x[0]
        self.trigDict[itemToChange][2] = x[2]
        self.trigDict[itemToChange][3] = x[3]


#The following function is for a remote update from a different class
#This fails with a 'TypeError:'
    def progUpdate(self, y): #y again is a list
        itemToChange = y[0]
        self.trigDict[itemToChange][2] = y[2]
        self.trigDict[itemToChange][3] = y[3]

class ...other screens and manager

#The following Popup is called from a button in the main functions
class MassSetPopup(Popup):
    settingID = ''
    settingPart = StringProperty()
    settingLoc = StringProperty()
    settingNum = StringProperty()
    full_num = ''
    new_lineData = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(MassSetPopup, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def on_parent(self, *args):
            self.settingPart = self.new_lineData[1]
            self.settingLoc = self.new_lineData[2]
            self.settingNum = self.new_lineData[3]


    def num_clk(self, x):
            if x == 'Bksp':
                    self.full_num = self.full_num[:-1]
                    self.settingNum = self.full_num
                    self.new_lineData[3] = self.full_num

            elif len(x) > 3:
                    self.settingLoc = x
                    self.new_lineData[2] = x

            elif len(self.full_num) == 4:
                    pass

            else:
                    self.full_num = self.full_num+x
                    self.settingNum = self.full_num
                    self.new_lineData[3] = self.full_num

    def save_point(self):
            setScreen.progUpdate(setScreen, self.new_lineData)
            self.dismiss()

    def cancel_point(self):
            print(self.new_lineData)
            self.dismiss()
```

I have placed the returning data in a non ListProperty list in the setScreen class as a test and it is updating properly from the Popup class.

All the .kv widgets load properly and screens/popups do what is expected.

I have been struggling with this for a couple days and have searched high an low but could not find anything that fit this issue, or even pointed me in the right direction, at least to my novice Python coding.

Comment: Ok, I have figured out that my issue is not in passing the data back to the ListProperty, but in Passing it to the correct instance of the setScreen. I need to look at how to pass information from my popup back to the calling instance of the setScreen class.

Comment: Worked this out. I ended up binding the 'on_dismiss' handler of the Popup to the 'progUpdate' function. This updates the ListProperty in the correct instance and the Kivy labels are updated as expected without the 'TypeError:'.